# ASP .NET - Diretório local do arquivo utilizando o Chrome

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, asp.net

Tenho o seguinte trecho de código:

```
<div class='upload-border'>
   <input class='file-upload' id="fileUpload" runat="server" type="file" name='upload'/>
</div>
```

Preciso pegar o diretório local do arquivo que eu acabei selecionar. Com C#, quando eu utilizo fileUpload.Value no Internet Explorer, está me retornando o diretório correto, por exemplo: C:\temp\meuarquivo.txt. No Chrome, apenas me retorna o nome do arquivo.

Preciso do diretório completo, pois preciso salvar esse conteúdo.

Como posso pegar o diretório completo com C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amigo devido a questões de política de segurança o google chrome não mostra o caminho do arquivo, ele sempre mostra um "fakepath" no lugar do caminho local da máquina, o que você pode fazer em c# é submitar o form que está o seu input file e pegar o arquivo com

```
Request.Files["nameInput"].
```

Espero ter ajudado.